# Expand directory name of currently opened buffer in ex-mode

Tags: vim

I want to invoke the cscope command with the current working directory as the argument. I have set up Vim to change its CWD to the currently opened buffer. If I have an opened buffer of the file "C:\dir\subdir\file.d", I'd like to issue this call:

```
:cscope add C:\dir\subdir
```

Without having to manually type the directory name, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does :cscope behaves with `:cscope %:p:h` ? (some command accepts this form, some not)